# Multiple values in a single macro definition with __SYSCALL_DEFINEx

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor

I am trying to understand a chunk of code from /include/linux/syscall.h, where a macro definition seems to have multiple values, with semicolons separating each one of them:

```
 235 #define __SYSCALL_DEFINEx(x, name, ...)                                 \
 236         __diag_push();                                                  \
 237         __diag_ignore(GCC, 8, "-Wattribute-alias",                      \
 238                       "Type aliasing is used to sanitize syscall arguments");\
 239         asmlinkage long sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_DECL,__VA_ARGS__))       \
 240                 __attribute__((alias(__stringify(__se_sys##name))));    \
 241         ALLOW_ERROR_INJECTION(sys##name, ERRNO);                        \
 242         static inline long __do_sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_DECL,__VA_ARGS__));\
 243         asmlinkage long __se_sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_LONG,__VA_ARGS__)); \
 244         asmlinkage long __se_sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_LONG,__VA_ARGS__))  \
 245         {                                                               \
 246                 long ret = __do_sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_CAST,__VA_ARGS__));\
 247                 __MAP(x,__SC_TEST,__VA_ARGS__);                         \
 248                 __PROTECT(x, ret,__MAP(x,__SC_ARGS,__VA_ARGS__));       \
 249                 return ret;                                             \
 250         }                                                               \
 251         __diag_pop();                                                   \
 252         static inline long __do_sys##name(__MAP(x,__SC_DECL,__VA_ARGS__))
```

I haven't seen this before, and couldn't find any reference to this. What `__SYSCALL_DEFINEx(x, name, ...)` does when defined in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where a macro definition seems to have multiple values

A macro doesn't have any values. A macro is a token manipulation construct. When the preprocessor expands it, it turns (zero or more) inputs token into output tokens. The output tokens just have to be valid tokens, they don't even need to be valid C code. For instance:

```
#define foo(t) 1 > 0 t 0 : 1
```

That's a perfectly valid function-like macro definition. When we write `foo(;)` or `foo(3)` the preprocessor substitutes the argument into the token sequence it spits out. Of course, for the arguments we provided, the result is syntactically invalid C. But `foo(?)` *would* result in valid C.

The point of that preamble was to explain that those semicolons don't do anything special. They are just part of the token sequence the macro spits out. That macro is designed to replace itself by a sequence of declarations and function definitions that implement a system call. Declarations and statements in the bodies of functions must terminate with a `;`. Nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are not seeing a macro definition with multiple values, you are seeing a macro definition which spans in multiple lines. So basically, __SYSCALL_DEFINEx(x, name, ...) will be replaced by the whole block of code below it (note that the \ at the end of the line is for spanning multiple lines, and of course, each line of code should be ended with a ;).